# window.webkit in Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webkit

I need to rewrite a javascript code into typescript (angular), the webpage is opened by an IOS app or an Android app. I just want to send a message to the application.

How can i do to send a message to the parent app or how can i use `window.webkit` ?

```
notifyTheApp(postData) {
  if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad)/)) {
    if(window.webkit.messageHandlers)      
     window.webkit.messageHandlers.mpos.postMessage(JSON.stringify(postData));
    } 
    else {
      if(window.external.notify)
        window.external.notify(JSON.stringify(postData));
    }
```

`mpos` is the iOS application

> **ERROR in src/app/sms-validation/sms-validation.component.ts(98,17): error TS2339: Property 'webkit' does not exist on type 'Window'.**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use type assertion (https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-assertion.html) to temporarily cast `window` the `any` type. You will loose intellisense for that statement though.

```
(window as any).webkit.messageHandlers
```

Answer (score 4):

I reckon `window.webkit` is pretty far from the standard, and it's therefore not part of the `window` type in Typescript. You can add it like this:

```
interface Window {
    webkit?: any;
}

declare var window: Window;
```

Note that `webkit?` means that the property is optional, so you should do some checking on whether the property exists or not.

Comment: Where should I add this code? I added it to the function, it's compiling but it returns an error : " ERROR in src/app/sms-validation/sms-validation.component.ts(105,5): error TS1184: Modifiers cannot appear here."

Comment: If you add it to the same file, it has to be a module: http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAbwL4G4BQaAmwDGAbAQymDgHM8IAjAvRNOOASwDsZgoAzAnEgdRcwQA7nQYMhwSgGtGMAPwAuOAWYBPdAyRotaIQOEA6CdNlwAZGbh7mgoUckyYRgBYE2AN3YAKAJQogA

Answer (score 0):

Just add in any loaded typescript file.

```js
declare global{
  interface Window {
    webkit?: {
      messageHandlers: {
        [x:string]: {
          postMessage: (data: string) => void;
        };
    };
  };
};
```

Answer (score -1):

I guest you are using webView if you not forget window.webkit . 
You must define it first , by default there is no object (in window):

```
  window.webkit
```

Just add it :

```
 let contentController = self.webView.configuration.userContentController
 contentController.addScriptMessageHandler(self, name: "callbackHandler")


 let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
 config.userContentController = contentController


 let webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect.zero, configuration: config)

 // Add callback func 

 func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {

     // message.name is "callbackHandler"
     // message.body is ["programming":"js"]
 }
```

Now you can call in your browser env :

```
  var message = {'programming':'js'};
  window.webkit.messageHandlers.callbackHandler.postMessage(message);
```

Reference :

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKUserContentController_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKUserContentController/addScriptMessageHandler:name:

Comment: the question is about the web-side typescript code, not the iOS code. I've also done this part already, but need to adapt the typescript interface for `Window`